# Error: $injector:unpr Unknown provider: $localStorageProviderProvider <- $localStorageProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ng-storage

I am trying to use `ngStorage` to store some data in my `localStorage`. But I get the following error, which is very strange to me:

> Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider Unknown provider:
>   $localStorageProviderProvider <- $localStorageProvider
>
> https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$localStorageProviderProvider%20%3C-%20$localStorageProvider

I'm using typescript as well. Here is my code:

app.module.ts:

```
(() => {

    angular.module(App.Config.MODULE_NAME, [
        'ngRoute',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ngStorage',
        'toastr',
    ]);

})();
```

register.controller.ts:

```
namespace App.Components.Register {
"use strict";
import IUser = App.Interfaces.IUser;
import UserDataService = App.Services.Http.UserDataService;
import IStorageProvider = angular.storage.IStorageProvider;
import ILocationService = angular.ILocationService;
import LogService = App.Services.Util.LogService;

export class RegisterController extends BaseController {

    public user: IUser;

    public static $inject: string[] = ['$localStorageProvider', '$location', 'LogService', 'UserDataService'];

    constructor(private $localStorageProvider: IStorageProvider,
                private $location: ILocationService,
                private logService: LogService,
                private UserDataService: UserDataService) {
        super();
    }

    public submit() {
        this.UserDataService.create(this.user).then(
            (data) => {
                switch (data.status) {
                    case 1:
                        this.logService.success("Usuário criado com sucesso.");
                        this.$localStorageProvider.set("user", this.user);
                        this.$location.path("/");
                        break;
                    case -1:
                        this.logService.error("Erro na criação do usuário.");
                        this.user.password = null;
                        break;
                    case -2:
                        this.logService.warning("Nome de usuário já está sendo utilizado.");
                        this.user.username = null;
                        this.user.password = null;
                        break;
                    case -3:
                        this.logService.warning("Este e-mail já está sendo utilizado.");
                        this.user.email = null;
                        this.user.password = null;
                        break;
                }
            },
            (error) => {
                this.logService.error(error);
                this.user.password = null;
            }
        );
    }
}

angular.module(App.Config.MODULE_NAME).controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);
}
```

The strange thing for me is that if I use `$localStorage` instead of `$localStorageProvider` it doesn't raise any error, but I won't have the `get()/set()` function of the Provider.

The second thing that is strange to me is the error message generated by angular:

> Unknown provider: $localStorageProviderProvider <-
>   $localStorageProvider

Where did that second Provider on `$localStorageProviderProvider` came from?

I know I have workarounds, but this error is just getting into my head and I can't let it go until I discover the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does "I won't have the get()/set() function of the Provider" mean?  `$localStorage` is the **correct** way to load the module, there is no provider for a service/factory called `$localStorageProvider` (hence no `$localStorageProviderProvider`).  Perhaps you should ask a different question, about why certain features of `$localStorage` aren't available as expected when it its injected...

Comment: I am following the instruction on the github page of the ngStorage https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage, and if you go to "Usage from config phase" there he uses the $localStorageProvider with the get()/set() methods.

`var app = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage'])
.config(['$localStorageProvider',
    function ($localStorageProvider) {
        $localStorageProvider.get('MyKey');

        $localStorageProvider.set('MyKey', { k: 'value' });
    }]);`

Comment: because providers are handled differently in `.config` phase.  your code shows you trying to inject this into a controller, not config, so what you are trying to do won't work.

Comment: so i just can't use the provider by injecting to a controller? at least now it makes more sense. thanks, then!

Comment: the only reason to inject a provider, aside from trying to work around doing things out of phase, is to modify the way a service/factory will be delivered.  The config phase is what this is for.